# How do I set up MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb

I need to work with MongoDB Atlas but unsure how to set it up?  I have never used Cloud DB before.  I want to make sure that I can let everyone connect to it without an API Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign up with MongoDB Atlas
Go to the MongoDB Atlas website and sign up: https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas
Fill in the form to create your account:
Once you are in, it will ask you to select a path for clustering.  Select the Free option at this time.

Then it will ask you to create a starter cluster

All default settings are fine
Encourage you to rename your cluster and then Click Create

After about a minute, it’s created

Click on Collections button
For first time use it will ask if you want sample data
If you just need sample data to play with, click on Load a Sample Dataset

For that, just follow the prompts
All your data will load

Next click on Database Access, we will need to create a database user

Keep it easy, use a password and select the role that this user should have
Click Add User
Now we need to white List IPs

Click on Network Access
Then click on Add IP, then "allow access from anyone" (No need for API Key)
You can always change this later but for testing purposes, you can select this
Click Confirm

Wait until it states that it’s active

Now click on Cluster and Connect
Select Connect using MongoDB Compass

Leave settings as is and copy the string and make the changes
For our purposes, here is our connection string.
mongodb+srv://Cam_user:Password1@camcluster.l41xe.mongodb.net/sample_airbnb